# In relativity, perpendicular motion does not show contraction... Isn't the whole concept lost?

Tags: special-relativity, velocity

I read in HC Verma's *Concept of Physics* that a body moving in direction perpendicular to length, doesn't show *Length Contraction*. And *Length Contraction*, they said, is to maintain the velocity of light constant, while still in relative motion to it. If a body doesn't show contraction (which is in this case), how is the speed of light kept constant? ( ***I am still a beginner in Relativity with no teacher as I am a Pre-Med and just excuse me if this is an idiotic question, but please clarify it anyway***).

Comment: I think this is a result of most examples of length contraction being rulers and rockets travelling near the speed of light, where it makes it seem as though the long part of the object (e.g. ruler, rockets, etc.) has some sort of directional preference when it comes to relativistic effects. As said in the answer, length contraction happens along the direction of velocity (all relative to an observer).

Comment: There's really no need to yell.

Comment: Reread the passage from the book.  If it really says "a body moving in direction perpendicular to length, doesn't show Length Contraction", then throw it in the trash and buy a new book.  If the book is so unclear about this topic, you can't trust it to be clear on other topics.

Answer (score 3):

A body with finite dimensions will always contract in the direction of motion. A square sheet will contract in either direction by a factor of $L = L_0/\gamma$ where $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$. A sheet moving in both directions will experience contraction in both dimensions.

Length contraction is motivated, as you say, by a need to keep the speed of light (the velocity of the propagation of interaction) constant in all reference frames. The most common derivation involves a moving train car and a light bulb, where the velocity of light from the bulb must be constant in the rest and comoving reference frame. Length doesn't contract in the direction perpendicular to the velocity, since there is no motion relative to the rest frame.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood something.Length contraction in a moving body,does not occur in the perpendicular direction of its **velocity** (not length as you mentioned). Length contraction occurs in the direction of its motion.

Answer (score 1):

The measured length of an object along the line of relative motion is contracted while measured lengths perpendicular to the motion are not.

[image]

[Image credit](http://www.askamathematician.com/2011/01/q-why-does-lorentz-contraction-only-act-in-the-direction-of-motion/)